# How to bring 1 window in front of other apps, not others?

Tags: macos, nswindow

Using code, not user interaction, how do you bring one of an app's windows to the front of other apps, and make it key, while leaving the rest of your app's windows alone?

(The effect I'm after is exactly like clicking on an app window. That window comes above all other app's windows, becomes key, it's first responder gains focus, but the rest of the app's windows do not come forward.)